# Multiple Mercurial repositories or a single one with clones

Tags: mercurial

We are working on a big project organized in 4 teams (website, server, applet, deployment). Sometimes members of each teams have to make minor changes in the code of the other team (*for instance: a member from the applet team has to add a field in the website, or a member of the server team has to change a deployment script*).

For the moment every team has its own mercurial repository, and we are using version number to organize dependencies between teams. (*The applet version 3.4 needs the website version 1.7*)

I think that our mercurial organisation is not optimal, my idea is to have one big mercurial repository **MASTER**, which will be cloned in **WEBSITE**, **SERVER**, **APPLET** and **DEPLOYMENT**. Each member of each team can have access to the code of others and they are not impacted by the commit of other teams because of the different clones.

What the SO community think about that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should maintain separate repositories for separate components, and other separate repos for any pieces shared between components (libraries if you will).  Then use the [subrepository](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository) feature to have the component repos include the shared stuff.

Merging everything into one large repo works well in svn, but in Mercurial, or any DVCS, you're better off with a composition of smaller repos.

Comment: +1 I agree. In fact I'm trying to organize a framework project exactly like that. Each project have his own separate repo. Then I have another repo that gather all the repos by using the subrepo features. Then to make each project aware of the location of other projects as dependencies, I first thought of using subrepos in themselve but it felt wrong. I'm trying to setup a CMake-based organisation that makes possible working on separate projects independently(providing CMake path variables for dependencies) OR getting the "main" repo that have everything(in subrepo and CMake paths already set)